# How to change text color for all links in Materialize CSS navbar?

Tags: html, css, materialize

How do you change the text color for all navbar links including brand logo in Materialize css.  I tries to add like 'black-text' but it only works for the brand-logo. For example,

```
<a id="logo-container" href="#" class="brand-logo black-text">
    My Logo
</a>

<ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down black-text">
    <li><a href=#">Link 1</a> 
</li></ul>
```

Again 'black-text' only works for the logo.

Comment: This [page might be of some help](http://materializecss.com/sass.html) if you want to change large sections of the your website

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your css, add:

```
.black-text li a{
  color: black;
 }
```

alternately, you can add the "black-text" class directly to all the links you want to have black text.
example:

```
       <ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down black-text">
         <li><a class ="black-text" href=#">Link 1</a> 
      </li></ul>
```